# Xamarin Forms not showing Alert in andriod but in ios works fine

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a big question, 
The next code is in my test app,

```cs
namespace displayalertetst
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            a.Text = "asi";
            DisplayAlert("hola", "A", "as");
        }    
    }
}
```

The problem is, in Andriod, de Alert does not show, but in ios works fine ... why?

I already tried

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        a.Text = "asi";
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            DisplayAlert("hola", "A", "as");
        });
    }
}
```

And got the same behavior.

I am using visual studio for mac 8.1.4

and i am using xamarin forms 4.1

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if that's the cause of your issue but by the looks of [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayalert?view=xamarin-forms) this method returns a `Task`, meaning that it should be `await`'ed. Try calling it it like this `await DisplayAlert("hola", "A", "as");`. Make sure you add `async` keyword to your method

Comment: Hmmm i tried your exact code, with Xamarin Forms version 3.10.0.1008975, and then I updated to the latest version of Xamarin Forms nuget package (4.1.0.555618) on the Core and Android projects, and it worked on both. If you update the package does it work, there could have been a bug?

Comment: you need to await on async task, otherwise it will run synchronously causing not to display at times

Comment: Saamer, thanks, I think too is a bug too of the release, I've not have much time lately but I will try today all the comments you have posted, Thanks to all !

Comment: @carlos Hi ,if have solved , you can share solution in answer.

Comment: Hello !!! @JuniorJiang-MSFT nothing has worked, it simple does not execute that part of the code in the first start of the app, I had to code the exception, is really weird

Comment: @carlos Got it, I have updated an answer to suggest to update to current latest version to have a try . If also not shown , I will submit it as an issue to GitHub .

Answer (score 0):

You can update **Visual Studio 2019 for Mac** to the latest version `8.3.5` to have a try again , it is released on October 28, 2019 .

And now **Xamarin Forms** latest version is `4.3` , you need to keep them with all the latest .